# Use Autowired to get instance after application request is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I need to get the ConnectionFactory instance which is generated using Spring Boot Application startup,

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
     }

}

public class Consumer {

    @Autowired Config config;

    public void request(Queue queue) {
        ConnectionFactory cf=config.connectionFactory();
    }
}
```

I am getting the config object as null even if the value is auto wired and is there any way to get the connection factory instance after the SpringBoot application is loaded.

Is it possible to get the instance without using static and currently? I am setting the instance to static object and retrieving it but I need to use the existing connection factory instance without static method.

**Please suggest how to implement this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Bean` registers a `ConnectionFactory` instance with the Spring bean factory. So you should `@Autowire` that. And `Consumer` should be marked as `@Component` or equivalent so that Spring can manage populating `@Autowired` beans.

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

   @Autowired ConnectionFactory cf;

     public void request(Queue queue) {
        // use the connection factory here
     }
}
```

Comment: I am getting connectionFactory instance also as null when I am trying to hit the request.

Comment: How is the `Consumer` object created?

Comment: I have created an instance of Consumer cons=new Consumer(); on GET API request call and using the instance I am consuming the cons.request(q) method call.

Comment: When you create a Consumer that way, Spring cannot autowire it's dependencies. You should autowire Consumer too.

Comment: Thanks it helps, but there is a new connection creating everytime even it is singleton  scope why there is a new connection is getting created and I want to reuse the same connection instance.